# What's the design pattern I must draw attention when i develop vector editor?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

What's the design pattern I must draw attention when i develop vector editor?

Now I use composite pattern (composite draw objects) and fabric method - for creation draw objects, which make user.

And what is the patterns i can use for my vector editor?

Comment: This is a very vague and broad question.

Comment: What is the tool I need to build a house ? I already used a screwdriver to fix the doors. What are the tools I can use to build my house ?

Comment: @Alex nice metaphor paraphrasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need these:

- Composite Pattern
- Visitor Pattern
- Command Pattern

And after that, you may need these as well:

- Strategy
- Decorator
- Observer